# JQuery Mobile dynamic background color of 'li'

Tags: jquery-mobile

Trying to set the background color of my dynamic li. li is not given 'class' or 'id' since each li needs to have an assigned color in code.

```
$(data).find("#HospitalDescriptions").find('th').filter(function(){
    if (this.innerHTML !== '') {
        var bgcolor = $( this ).css( "background-color" );
        var txtcolor = $( this ).css( "color" );
        if (bgcolor !== ''){
            $('#information').append('<li><span style="background-color:' + bgcolor + ';color:' + txtcolor + ';">' + this.innerHTML + '</span></li>');
            $('li').css({backgroundColor: bgcolor});
        } else {
            $('#information').append('<li>' + this.innerHTML + '</li>');
        }
        }
    $('#information').listview('refresh');   // not working!
});
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="hospitals" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>HOSP-HEADER</h1>
        <a class="ui-btn-right" id="infoButton" onclick="$('#locations').listview('refresh');">Refresh</a>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" data-theme="b" id="regions">   

        <div data-role="content">
            <h4>Information</h4>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="information">
                <!-- AJAX CONTENT -->
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h4>Regions I, II, III</h4>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="region3">
                <!-- AJAX CONTENT -->
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h4>Region IV</h4>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="region4">
                <!-- AJAX CONTENT -->
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h4>Region V</h4>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="region5">
                <!-- AJAX CONTENT -->
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Powered by CM</h1>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div>
```

Results I'm getting now. text background color needs to fill the list view area not black:

[image]

Comment: Add this `style="background-color:' + bgcolor + ';color:' + txtcolor + ';` to `li` not `span`. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/cuyWL/

Comment: I knew it was something simple, thanks that fixed it... now I just need to center it.

Comment: `text-align: center;` to li as well. Even simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1
▲
text-align: center; to li as well. Even simpler. – Omar yesterday